# SwiftUIの@Publishedついて

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Appleのドキュメントを読んでいますが、理解できません。
[ドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published)

```
class Weather {
    @Published var temperature: Double
    init(temperature: Double) {
        self.temperature = temperature
    }
}

let weather = Weather(temperature: 20)
cancellable = weather.$temperature
    .sink() {
        print ("Temperature now: \($0)")
}
weather.temperature = 25
```

これを実行すると、
// Temperature now: 20.0
// Temperature now: 25.0
と返されるのですがなぜ、20.0も返されるのでしょうか？
Weatherクラスを生成した後、つまり既にtemperatureに値は入って後にパブリッシャーを登録しているので
20に関してはパブリッシャーが機能しないと思っていますが実際は、20も出力されます。

分かる方ぜひご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

weather.temperatureはCurrentValueSubjectなのでしょうねぇ。
[Subject | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subject)

期待された動作は、もう一つのSubject、PassthroughSubjectの方の様ですが。
e.g.

```swift
let relay = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

relay.send("Hello") // no output
let subscription = relay
    .sink { value in
        print("subscription1 received value: \(value)")
}

relay.send("World!") // => World!
```

比較のコード

```
let variable = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")

variable.send("Initial text")

let subscription2 = variable.sink { value in
    print("subscription2 received value: \(value)")
}

variable.send("More text")
// subscription2 received value: Initial text
// subscription2 received value: More text
```